# Проблемы типизации

Tags: java

Итак, у меня есть сущности, несколько штук.

```
InputField
CheckBoxField
SelectField
```

Все они наследуются от одной абстрактной сущности `AbstractEntity`.
Для каждой сущности есть репозиторий, наследующийся от CommonRepository:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CommonRepository<E extends AbstractEntity> extends JpaRepository<E, Long>
```

Я заавтовайрил репозитории в сервис:

```
@Service
public class ShiftServiceImpl implements ShiftService
```

и положил в мапу `<дискриминатор, бин репозитория>`, вот так:

```
private Map<String, CommonRepository> fieldRepositories;
fieldRepositories = new HashMap<>();
fieldRepositories.put("input", inputFieldRepository);
fieldRepositories.put("checkbox", checkBoxFieldRepository);
fieldRepositories.put("select", selectFieldRepository);
```

Далее, мне приходит дискриминатор сущности в виде `String`. И, определив по дискриминатору, что за сущность, я хочу дёрнуть нужную мне сущность через соответствующий бин репозитория. То есть, так:

```
fieldRepositories.get(e.get("type"))
                            .findById(id)
                            .ifPresent(i -> entities.add(i));
```

При этом, IDEA не даёт мне это сделать, подчёркивает последнюю `i` пишет:

```
add (ru.field.AbstractField) in List cannot be applied to
    (java.lang.Object)
```

Подскажите, как правильно типизировать класс / мапу, чтобы всё работало?

UPD:

Заработало, благодаря ответу коллеги, но теперь не до конца чекает тип (Unchecked cast):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD2:

Помог комментарий, но теперь отвалилось в другом месте, при сохранении сущности:

```
    entities
            .forEach(e -> {
                fieldRepositories.get(e.getFieldType().getName()).save(e);
            });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А так `entities.add((ru.field.AbstractField) i)`?

Comment: спасибо, помогло. но как дочекать тип (приложил фото)?

Comment: киньте гит проекта. по вашему описанию вообще ничего не понятно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понял все репозитории в `fieldRepositories` работают с сущностями-наследниками `AbstractField`, а `entities` — коллекция `AbstractField`.

Ошибка заключается в том, что из `fieldRepositories` это никак не ясно, ведь в него можно добавить другой репозиторий, у которого `findById` вернет объект, никак не связанный с `AbstractField`.

Исправить можно так:

```
private Map<String, CommonRepository<? extends AbstractField>> fieldRepositories;
```

Теперь в `fieldRepositories` не получится добавить «неправильный» объект — произойдет ошибка компиляции.

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ:** Да, проблема с типизацией тут глубже. Ошибка в этом коде:

```
entities
            .forEach(e -> {
                fieldRepositories.get(e.getFieldType().getName()).save(e);
            });
```

говорит о том, что компилятор не уверен, что в словаре каждой сущности сопоставлен нужный репозиторий.

Например, по ошибке ключ в словаре может отличаться от `e.getFieldType().getName()`. Или где-то между сбором и сохранением сущностей Вы можете сделать что-то вроде `fieldRepositories.put("input", checkBoxFieldRepository);`

Знать, что сопоставление сущность—репозиторий правильное компилятор не может. Этой информации в коде нет. Правильность зависит только от внимательности разработчика, который заполняет `Map`. Т.ч. боюсь, обойтись совсем без приведения типов здесь не получится.

Заставить компилятор проглотить ошибку можно так:

```
entities
            .forEach(e -> {
                ((CommonRepository<AbstractField>)fieldRepositories.get(e.getFieldType().getName())).save(e);
            });
```

Но приведение, тем более непроверенное, выглядит некрасиво. Если без приведения не обойтись, то обычно его стараются изолировать в отдельный метод, например:

```
//объявление возвращаем, т.к. приведение вынесено в метод
private Map<String, CommonRepository> fieldRepositories;

/**
* Отдельный метод для получения репозитория типа `AbstractField`.
* Так приведение будет только в одном месте. 
* Предупреждение компилятора гасим аннотацией.
*/        
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
CommonRepository<AbstractField> getRepository(Map<String, CommonRepository> map, String key) {
    return (CommonRepository<AbstractField>) map.get(key);
}

//Примеры использования

//поиск
getRepository(e.get("type"))
                            .findById(id)
                            .ifPresent(i -> entities.add(i));

//сохранение
entities.forEach(e -> {
                getRepository(e.getFieldType().getName()).save(e);
            });
```

Строго типизированное решение мне сейчас в голову не приходит. Может кто-нибудь предложит какой-нибудь изощренный вариант.

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов Тут уже без каста у меня обойтись не получилось. Добавил в ответ свой вариант решения.

Comment: в итоге, кастомизировал в CommonRepository. Спасибо.

Comment: теперь та же проблема вылезла в другом месте, и этот рецепт почему-то не помог. создал отдельную тему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/992243/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2 @defaultlocale