# Типизация объектов

Tags: java

У меня есть класс `AppealTemlate`, который содержит список сущностей `extends AbstractField`. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
public class AppealTemplate extends AbstractEntity {
    private List<AbstractField> fields = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Реализаций `AbstractField` несколько, около полудюжины. Когда на маппер приходит `AppealTemplate`, маппер не знает, какие именно сущности лежат в списке, поэтому на первое время я сделал такую реализацию маппинга fields в DTO:

```
source.getFields()
                    .forEach(f -> {
                        if (f.getFieldType().equals(FieldType.CHECKBOX)) {
                            destination.getFields().add(checkBoxFieldMapper.toDto((CheckBoxField) f));
                        } else if (f.getFieldType().equals(FieldType.DATE_PICKER)) {
                            ...
}
```

Выглядит макаронно, поэтому я решил переписать на более лаконичный вариант. Я заавтовайрил все мапперы и создал отдельную мапу с мапперами, доставаемыми оттуда по ключу:

```
private Map<String, EntityDtoMapper<? extends AbstractField, ? extends AbstractFieldDto>> fillMappers() {
    mappers = new HashMap<>();
    mappers.put(FieldType.DATE_PICKER.getName(), datePickerFieldMapper);
    mappers.put(FieldType.CHECKBOX.getName(), checkBoxFieldMapper);
    ...
}
```

Далее, я пытаюсь сделать следующее:

```
source.getFields()
                .forEach(f -> {
                    destination.getFields().add(mappers.get(f.getFieldType().getName()).toDto((AbstractField) f));
```

Но часть кода `((AbstractField) f)` подчёркивает красным и пишет, что toDto() не может быть применено к `AbstractField`, потому что оно ожидает `capture<? extends AbstractField>`.

Я уже задавал подобный вопрос [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/990343/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)
и мне здорово помог пользователь @defaultlocale
Но в этот раз почему-то этот рецепт не работает, хотя, сущности те же и всё то же.

UPD: уточняющая информация:

```
private Map<String, EntityDtoMapper<? extends AbstractField, ? extends AbstractFieldDto>> mappers;
```

toDto():

```
@Override
public D toDto(E entity) {    //E extends AbstractEntity, D extends AbstractDto
    return Objects.isNull(entity)
            ? null
            : mapper.map(entity, dtoClass);    //private Class<D> dtoClass;
}
```

В разложенном на переменные виде интересующая часть кода выглядит так:

```
fields
         .forEach(f -> {
            List<AbstractFieldDto> destinationFields = destination.getFields();
            EntityDtoMapper<? extends AbstractField, ? extends AbstractFieldDto> entityDtoMapper
                    = mappers.get(f.getFieldType().getName());
            AbstractField abstractField = f;
            AbstractFieldDto abstractFieldDto = entityDtoMapper.toDto(abstractField);
            destinationFields.add(abstractFieldDto);
```

Comment: обычный геттер: public List<AbstractField> getFields() для source и соответственно public List<AbstractFieldDto> getFields() для destination. Маппер получает fields и наполняет этот список преобразованными в DTO сущностями.

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Comment: Необходимость проверять тип - это маркер архитектурных проблем. Типами должен заниматься компилятор, а в рантайме data flow должен быть абсолютно прозрачным.

Comment: Вячеслав, есть конечно талантливые люди у которых в голове java компилятор, но это достаточно не тривиальная задача в общем случае, по фрагментам кода определить где ошибка, вы задали вопрос и я не спорю что не принято в вопрос добавлять простыню кода, но поставьте себя на место потенциального отвечающего. вот я бы лично открыл код в своей ide и там уже все посмотрел. К чему это я, воспользуйтесь каким нибудь pastebin, чтобы предоставить исходник, который можно скопировать и вставить, иначе это нужно восстанавливать из франментов, а это время. и да спасибо что не скриншотом.

Comment: к сожалению, исходники выдать не могу

Comment: те которые нужны для пороверки проблемы, минимизируйте его так чтобы она воспроизводилась и все, остальное можно удалить

Comment: на это полдня уйдёт, а мне не за то платят, чтобы я исходники выкладывал на pastebin даже в обрезанном виде :)

Comment: подскажите, как призвать человека по никнейму? у меня не получается призвать сюда того человека, который мне помог в прошлый раз :)

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов используйте @ username

Comment: @AndrewBystrov работает только если человек в комментариях уже отметился.

Comment: почему toDto(E entity) если там должно быть E field?

Comment: @alex сбросьте, пожалуйста, все доступные наименования параметров, чтобы я впредь не думал о нейминге.

Comment: @Вячеслав Чернышов, я не про то. Почему в комментарии написано extends AbstractEntity. Не AbstractField?

Comment: вы не привели код EntityDtoMapper. По моему он ключевой в вашей проблеме